# How to re-export global.d.ts typings for a third-party javascript project?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, pouchdb, .d.ts

Although I can create typings that allow my typescript modules to ***consume*** function definitions from a third-party javascript module, this seems to create problems in turn for packages importing my module.

I populated a global.d.ts file to add the following typings for my typescript project since [pouchdb-collate](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/tree/master/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-collate) is a pure javascript project with no @types package...

```js
// global.d.ts
declare module "pouchdb-collate" {
  export function toIndexableString(item: any): string;
  export function parseIndexableString(indexableString: string): any;
}
```

This works well in my monorepo within project A which uses pouchdb-collate and has the `global.d.ts` in its `src/`. However, whenever I import project A into project B in monorepo, the typings of pouchdb-collate are then unavailable to the project B, which results in an error like...

```
    ../collate/src/index.ts:4:8 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'pouchdb-collate'. '/project/blabla/node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-collate@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-collate/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
      Try `npm i --save-dev @types/pouchdb-collate` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'pouchdb-collate';`
```

That is even though there is already a global.d.ts file in the `collate/src` folder containing exactly that syntax, and which provided the correct types when running scripts from within the folder!

I can only fix this by placing another copy of `global.d.ts` in project B as well.

As an alternative I have tried to create a package C within the monorepo that contains a `global.d.ts` and reexports the symbols from `pouchdb-collate` via an `index.ts` file like...

```js
// modules/collate/src/index.ts
export { parseIndexableString, toIndexableString } from "pouchdb-collate";
```

The benefit of this approach (aliasing via a package) would be to eventually replace those functions with versions vendored in, rewritten and tested in typescript. However, this approach suffers from the same issue.

What is the way for package C to re-export the symbols AND suitable typings for this third-party package so that projects importing package C can consume them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case I succeeded at re-exporting the third-party module with typings as below.

First I created a new module in my monorepo called @blabla/collate that imported and re-exported in pure javascript like...

```js
// src/index.js
module.exports = require("pouchdb-collate");
```

Next to it I placed a file called `index.d.ts` declaring types for my new package...

```js
// src/index.d.ts
declare module "@blabla/collate" {
  export function toIndexableString(item: any): string;
  export function parseIndexableString(indexableString: string): any;
}
```

As recommended by the typescript docs, I then added values to the `package.json` of `@blabla/collate` as follows...

```json
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "types": "src/index.d.ts",
```

So this doesn't directly type the `pouchdb-collate` package, but it does re-export via normal javascript mechanisms, then exports declarations for the new javascript source file.

Feels like there should be a more elegant approach so I won't mark this as the answer yet in case anyone has a contribution to make.

Comment: As for typings, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Emit_6246